# Version of lexical_cast that doesn't use exceptions

Tags: c++, casting

I love `boost::lexical_cast` but its usage of exceptions there is not preferred in most situations I use it.

I have implemented a version and it seems to work but I want to share it here to hopefully find any defects and/or simply find improvements.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
T1 lexical_cast(T2 const& value, T1 const& defaultValue = T1{})
{
    T1 convertedValue;
    std::stringstream ss;
    if (!(ss << value) || !(ss >> convertedValue))
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    return convertedValue;
}
```

[Here is the code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3307fb9f2db79703) where I've been testing.

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost.Convert](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/convert/doc/html/boost_convert/introduction.html)?  *⟪choice of immediate or delayed exception-throwing and non-throwing conversion-failure processing⟫*

Answer (score 2):

I know I am quite late, but [`try_lexical_convert()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.try_lexical_convert) can be utilized:

```
using boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert;
if(try_lexical_convert(source, target)) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Could you explain to the OP how this code could be incorporated with his/her code? Should that function be used _instead_ of `lexical_cast` or before/after it?

Comment: The OP can figure it out by self, because it's enough to know the function name. I add answer there so as google searching for 'lexical_cast without exceptions' will give this sweet short answer.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process. Please read [Why are alternative solutions not welcome?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8404/120114)

Comment: Upvoted. This is a fantastic answer. According to Boost docs, `lexical_cast` is imlemented internally using `try_lexical_convert`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on C++17, you can use std::from_chars to convert your string into numerical values. It is much faster than boost::lexical_cast.

A sample usage can be:

```
int parsed_num{};
std::string to_parse{"123"};
std::from_chars(to_parse.begin(), to_parse.end(), parsed_num);
```

The function returns a struct with the error code and a pointer to the rest of the unparsed string. If the usage seems a little involved, you can always wrap it in a templated wrapper function that can define the variable for you, pass it to from_chars, and then return the result. One implementation can be:

```
#include <charconv>
#include <string_view>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <optional>

template<typename T, typename SAFE_PARSE_T=unsafe_parse>
[[nodiscard]] inline constexpr T parse(std::string_view sv, 
                                       const std::optional<T> default_val={}, 
                                       const char** next = nullptr)   
                                       noexcept(SAFE_PARSE_T::value)
{
  if constexpr(not SAFE_PARSE_T::value) {
    sv.remove_prefix(sv.find_first_not_of("+ ")); 
  }
  T var {default_val.value_or(T{})};
  auto ec = std::from_chars(sv.cbegin(), sv.cend(), var);
  if (next) *next = ec.ptr;
  if constexpr(not SAFE_PARSE_T::value) {
    if (default_val) {
      return var;
    }
    if(ec.ec!=std::errc{}) {
      throw std::runtime_error{"Parsing error!"};
    }
  }
  return var;
}
```

source: https://thecodepad.com/cpp/performant-string-parsing-in-cpp/

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an already working lexical cast. Why not just wrap that?

```
namespace MyStuff
{
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    T1 lexical_cast(T2 const& value, T1 const& defaultValue = T1{})
    {
        try
        {
            return boost::lexical_cast<T1,T2>(value);
        }
        catch(...) // Ignore all exceptions and use default.
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I would not advocate writing your own is the actually complicity of all the edge cases. Though your code embodies what is happening the actual code has not reflected this in a long time (you have basically written the deprecated version of boost::lexical cast).

Also the boost version has a whole bunch of special case optimizations.

Comment: The goal is to avoid exceptions. While I agree with your point about not reinventing the wheel, simply hiding the exception does not remove the performance impact.

Comment: I don't see exceptions being a real cost when you consider what we are doing - reading from a stream a slow operation most of the time. But I have not timed it. If you have some real data about the extra cost I would love to see it. Also is the extra cost greater than the speed saved by all the specializations specifically designed to increase the speed.

Comment: Also note: There is no extra cost if the exception is not thrown. So if you have good sanitized input then it will run faster than your code because of the specialization designed to increase speed in the boost::lexical_cast

Comment: You're missing the point. When I'm parsing a large XML file, for example, I don't need thousands of exceptions to occur which would negatively impact parse times. Exceptions are for exceptional situations, and in this case they are not exceptional (some failures are expected and can be recovered without the usage of exceptions).

Comment: @void.pointer: What I actually asked in the last comment do you have any data to support that there is actually a negative impact on parse time? Assuming you know what you have parsed and thus know it is a number already then why is boost::lexical_cast going to throw.

Comment: @void.pointer: The saying `Exceptions are for exceptional situations,` is really bad and does not actually explain what exceptions are for. A better one is `Exceptions are for situations where the error can not be fixed within the current context (because there is not the information required to fix the error in this context) and control must be moved to a higher level of context (that has a more general understanding) before corrective action can be taken.`

Comment: Exceptions have known overhead when throwing. I consider your suggestion a premature pessimisation simply because of experience.

Comment: Your explanation of what exceptions are for really have nothing to do with exceptions at all. Even when you use return codes, you may not be able to handle an error at that level, so you return error information so the next level up has an opportunity to handle the error. Exceptions *are* for exceptional situations, it's the one thing that helps me determine if an exception is appropriate or not (performance impact as well). It all comes down to context. I have to consider potential overhead based on experience.